# How to find how far I am from the other user?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write SQL query that I can find any user connected to my friend's friends but I stucked on the first level "mutual friends".

https://research.fb.com/three-and-a-half-degrees-of-separation

My example structure table "friends"

```
user1 | user2
1     | 2
1     | 3
2     | 3
5     | 7
```

Comment: Your example data leaves a bit to be desired. All of these nodes are either connected by 1 step or 0. Ultimately though, you need to write a recursive query to get what you are after. Please provide your desired results for the sample data provided (perhaps editted so there is more than one 1 layer of depth) so we can know what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Aaron, this is one the major disadvantage of using RDBMS. If you are planning to develop a application like FB or Twitter, I would recommend you to use Graph Database like Neo4J which does these things very efficiently. https://neo4j.com/

Newer versions of SQL Server (2017) also supports Graph concepts.. not sure how much flexible they are in comparison to Neo4J.